# endless container iterator with backward\forward movement support

Tags: python-3.x, containers, python-itertools

Is in standart library container with endless forward/backward movement support, like itertools.cycle? Or how to implement one-liner for it?

Current code ([github](https://github.com/pankshok/xoinvader/blob/master/xoi.py#L56)):

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    self.__weapons = [Weapon()("Blaster"), Weapon()("Laser"), Weapon()("UM")]
    self.__weapon = self.__weapons[0]
    ...

def next_weapon(self):
    ind = self.__weapons.index(self.__weapon)
    if ind < len(self.__weapons) - 1:
        self.__weapon = self.__weapons[ind+1]
    else:
        self.__weapon = self.__weapons[0]
```

And almost the same code for prev_weapon method.

I want to iterate on endless container in both directions=)

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: `Weapon()("Blaster")` did you mean `Weapon("Blaster")`, or does `Weapon()` create a callable? Also, instead of finding the index of the current weapon, why not just store the index itself? self.__index = 0` would make those two methods much simpler.

Comment: Why do you want it to be a oneliner?

Comment: `ind = (ind + 1) % len(self.__weapon)`? Also, is there any particular reason these attributes are double-underscored?

Comment: @tobias_k, yes, Weapon() create a calable.

Comment: @MarkWhitfield, because __weapon is a private member of Spaceship class:)

Comment: @miindlek, maybe not one-liner, but simple in use container, if it's possible without writing it from scratch. cycle is good, but it can't return previous item.

Comment: Secondary to your question, but "Private member" is not really something that exists/is used in Python. This is not what double underscores are used for. First of all, double-underscore names can still be accessed -- there's no such thing as a truly "private" attribute. The usage is to prevent subclasses from overriding the attribute (through name-mangling). Is this really something you need? I ask because the double-underscore tends to be greatly overused by those from a C++/Java background.

If all you mean is to indicate "don't touch this, please", that's what a single-underscore is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided that best solution is to extend List.

```
class InfList(list):
"""Infinite list container"""

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self._index = 0


def current(self):
    return self[self._index]


def next(self):
    self._index = (self._index + 1) % len(self)
    return self[self._index]


def prev(self):
    self._index = (self._index - 1) % len(self)
    return self[self._index]
```